# Факап парсера в VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Проект на плюсах.
В файле `d3deffect`, что находится в каталоге `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um`, обнаружилась забавная хрень:

парсер студии воспринимает как ошибку конструкцию вида

```
STDMETHOD_(ID3D10EffectConstantBuffer*, GetParentConstantBuffer)(THIS) PURE;
```

и аналогичные ей.
Прикол в том, что если развернуть макрос (вручную заменить параметры и тупо подставить), а именно

```
#define STDMETHOD_(type,method)  virtual COM_DECLSPEC_NOTHROW type
STDMETODCALLTYPE method
virtual COM_DECLSPEC_NOTHROW ID3D10EffectVariable* _stdcall GetMemberByIndex(THIS_ UINT Index) PURE;
```

то все становится снова хорошо.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

Comment: Парсер == IntelliSense? Или компилятор? Какая ошибка?

Comment: http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20130716/NMMhBUYR.png

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CSg3NHWM

Comment: @Котик, вторая вставка - ошибки компилятора

Comment: @SoloMio: Думаю, у вас неправильно подключено DirectX SDK, не прописаны пути к хедерам.

Comment: @VladD, да нет, все хедеры прописаны (и либы тоже)

Comment: @SoloMio: А пути к ним в настройках? Ещё бывает важен порядок (да, это баг в хедерах): попробуйте включать пути SDK перед (или после, не помню точно) остальных путей в опциях компилятора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В-общем отвечаю сам на свой вопрос, вдруг у кого-то тоже возникнет такая же проблема, думаю данная информация безусловно может пригодиться.
К сожалению, в Visual Studio 2012 нет совершенно никакой возможности настроить порядок или приоритет одних директорий для поиска заголовочных файлов перед другими.
Поэтому для решения данной проблемы небоходимо сделать следующее:

1. Включить флаг /X, отменяющий поиск заголовочных файлов в стандартных подключаемых директориях, а-ля Windows Kit и другие, как это сделать пошагово написано здесь: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93t31bx4.aspx
2. Добавить все необходимые папки для вашего проекта вручную, первым в списке должен идти пуь к вашему DirectX SDK.

P.S. Ненавижу Microsoft.

Comment: А почему не пойдёт отредактировать свойства проекта и перетасовать список стандартных заголовочных директорий? Свойства проекта -> VC++ directories -> Include directories, у меня стоит по умолчанию

    $(VCInstallDir)include
    $(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include
    $(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)

Comment: Дык а как?

Comment: Ну, раскрываете список (http://i.imgur.com/UEimpJe.png), нажимаете _Edit..._, редактируете, должно работать.